# What does VP mean in job titles?

Tags: abbreviations

What does "VP" mean in job titles?

It goes with different titles "VP of Acquiring", "VP of Strategic Alliances", "VP of Sales", "VP of Sales and Marketing" or "VP of Events".

Comment: Have a look at [define vp](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+vp) - it works for most words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VP - Vice president (you can find more information in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice_president))